# android: not detecting beacon

Tags: android, ibeacon

I have an activity that holds just single line in `onCreate()`

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyBeaconService.class));
```

**MyBeaconService.class**

```
public class MyBeaconService extends Service implements IBeaconConsumer{

    private IBeaconManager iBeaconManager = IBeaconManager
            .getInstanceForApplication(this);

    public MyBeaconService() {
        Log.i("MyBeaconService", "MyBeaconService");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onIBeaconServiceConnect() {
        Log.i("MyBeaconService", "onIBeaconServiceConnect");
        iBeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                Log.e("BeaconDetactorService", "didEnterRegion");
                 Log.i("BeaconDetactorService", "I just saw an iBeacon for the first time!");

                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(MyBeaconService.this, MyAdActivity.class);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(dialogIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                Log.e("BeaconDetactorService", "didExitRegion");
                // logStatus("I no longer see an iBeacon");
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.e("BeaconDetactorService", "didDetermineStateForRegion");
                // logStatus("I have just switched from seeing/not seeing iBeacons: "
                // + state);
            }

        });

        try {
            iBeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(new Region(
                    "myMonitoringUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("MyBeaconService", "onCreate");

        iBeaconManager.bind(this);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to detect any beacon.. I mean.. `didEnterRegion` method is never called..

Please help me with it..

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like you are using the Android iBeacon Library to detect beacons.  Is that correct?

Comment: @davidgyoung Yes sir.. Absolutely.. Actually, I didn't had much time to go through the documentation of iBeacon and it was urgent need to create a small demo in which an Activity starts which internally starts a service (which i have mentioned in question) and once it starts and detect for `didEnterRegion` it should start and activity.. thats it.. so I was not pretty sure why it was not working..

Answer (score 2):

A couple of tips:

- Make sure your mobile device can see your beacon with an off the shelf app like [Locate](http://store.radiusnetworks.com/products/locate-ibeacon-app).
- Make sure your debug lines show that `onIBeaconServiceConnect` is getting called. Is your service even starting?
- If the above method is getting called, try turning on low level debug in the library with: `iBeaconManager.setDebug(true)` and paste the output of what you see in LogCat in your question.
- The Library you are using was deprecated and replaced by the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) in July 2014.  If you intend to continue doing development with beacons, it would be wise to switch to the newer library.  It has a very similar syntax and design and gets bug fixes and ongoing support.  It also detects beacons in the background out of the box without the need to build your own service.

Note: I have revised this answer to remove a tip about method chaining which should not be necessary in this case.

Full disclosure: I am lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project and the author of the original Library used by the code in the question.